# Creating content of custom type in Share

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, opencmis

I am trying to have Share let the user create new documents based on a custom type I implemented (see the [excellent documentation here](http://ecmarchitect.com/images/articles/alfresco-content/content-article-2ed.pdf) )

I had the type implemented and defined aspects, but I can't see a clear way to configure Share in order to propose in the interface my type for a new document.

I guess it should be added to the Create content menu option that lists available types.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should just modify the `share-config-custom.xml` file in your `tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/web-extension` folder (if there is no such file, search for a similar sample file and rename it). There, you should put something like this in the `<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="DocumentLibrary" replace="true">` tag:

```
<types>
 <type name="custom:myType" />
</types>
```

Just remember if the replace parameter is true, you will override every type visible, so maybe it's better to turn it to false.
Hope it helps

Comment: this won't help. I'm using a file called `share-config-custom.xml` placed under `\tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\web-extension`

Comment: You shouldn't modify files inside webapps folder. Everything you change should be placed in the shared folder path. even the share config custom file.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to have it working by adding the following section to the `share-custom-config.xml` file:

```
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="DocumentLibrary">
    <create-content>
        <content id="plain-text" mimetype="text/plain" label="Brand new content type" itemid="sc:doc"/>
    </create-content>
</config>
```